# What does "相兼岂" mean in this sentence from a Taiji Quan manual?

Tags: traditional-characters, classical-chinese

The following sentence is from a short passage about "体用“ （utilizing/controlling the body) in the context of the 13 Forms of Taiji Quan:

"体用相兼岂有他浩然气能行乎手。掤捋按採挒肘靠進退顾盼定."

My current translation is as follows: "How else besides through control of the body can one have his vast amount of while being able to use the proper push-hands technique (Warding off, shifting, pressing, pushing, plucking, splitting, leaning, advancing and retreating, left, right, center)?"

I feel like I don't fully understand "相兼岂" in the sentence: could anyone confirm their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

the chopping of the verse is, . . . incorrect lah

the “體用歌”

> 太極拳。十三式。妙在二氣分陰陽。化生千億歸抱一。歸抱一。太極拳。兩儀四象渾無邊。禦風何似頂頭懸。我有一轉語。今為知者吐。湧泉無根腰無主。力學垂死終無補。**體用相兼豈有他**。浩然氣能行乎手。掤捋擠按採捩肘靠。進退顧盼定。不化自化走自走。足欲向前先挫後。身似行雲。打手安用手。渾身是手手非手。但須方寸隨時守所守。

roughly, “體” means “noumenon“ (本體); “用” means “usage” (使用)

so, the verse “體用相兼豈有他” should be interpreted as:

the noumenon (體) & usage (用), both (相) [should be] taken care of (兼 -> 兼顧); there’s no other way (豈有他)

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm reading more about the concept of “体用” thanks to your advice, and my translation should be a lot better as a result.